# GTA San Andreas Wine Installation fail

Tags: 18.04, wine, playonlinux

I have a problem while installing Grand Theft Auto San Andreas on my PC via wine. I have installed Wine versions 3.15, 3.5 and 1.7.35, and if I run Setup.exe on 3.15 or 3.5 (or with double click in Nautilus), it shows me window with title "Error" and text bellow `Runtime Error (at 71:174): Could not call proc.` and when I click OK, it shows me another window with title "Setup" and text `Runtime Error (at 141:113): Could not call proc.`

But on 1.7.35, when I run setup it only opens one unresponsive window showing just a little line in the center of the screen. Just now, installed Wine 1.9.10, tried to run Setup.exe via PlayOnLinux, and again opens unresponsive window named "Setup" and one more named "Wine Mono Installer", but still nothing happens. :/
Help?

Bump

Comment: I have succesfully installed Grand Theft Auto San Andreas, updated video card driver and now it says that GTA San Andreas needs at least DirectX9 which I already have installed o.O
How can I solve this?

Comment: Update: I can start installed .exe from PoL, but I can't start it from desktop icon showing me the error above.... -_-

Comment: Can you run the game without problem ? Just wondering...

Comment: I installed my Ubutnu 18.04 again, but I can't now install the game showing me the same error like above.

Comment: Any more help options?

Comment: Still haven't fixed the problem. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at Lutris, it handles games better than PoL and will probably lead to a running game.